# Fragment navigation from one fragment A to B in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, modal-dialog, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am implementing `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and when the user clicks on the button or the view itself I want to navigate to another Fragment from BottomSheetDialogFragment.

My App structure is like this

```
MainActivity -> FragmentContainerView -> Fragment1 -> Some Action happens -> BottomSheetDialogFragment ->  Click event -> Another Fragment should load inside BottomSheetDialogFragment (But app crashes)
```

Here is the layout and code for BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
class CommentaryViewFragment(private val commentaryNote: Note) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var titleTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var closeButton: ImageButton
    private lateinit var commentaryTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.verse_commentary_view, container, false)
        titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.commentary_title_text)
        closeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.commentary_close)
        commentaryTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.commentary_text)
        commentaryTextView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
        commentaryTextView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
        commentaryTextView.isFocusable = true
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val bottomSheet = view.parent as View
        bottomSheet.backgroundTintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR
        bottomSheet.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        bottomSheet.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        titleTextView.text = commentaryNote.ref
        commentaryTextView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        commentaryTextView.text = sampleText()
        commentaryTextView.setOnClickListener { pushNewFragment() }
        closeButton.setOnClickListener { this.dismiss() }
    }

    private fun pushNewFragment() {
        // App crashes here
        childFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, SingleVerseFragment())
            .commit()
    }
```

and the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/verse_commentary_view"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentary_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/crimsonpro"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Testing"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/commentary_close"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/commentary_view_close"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:fontFamily="@font/crimsonpro"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:id="@+id/commentary_text"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on CommentaryViewFragment and pushNewFragment is called I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a00e3 (org.apalpsiam.myapp:id/fragment_container_view) for fragment SingleVerseFragment{d435bc} (b803ec98-b83a-4390-9010-0ef5a495447f id=0x7f0a00e3)
```

[image]

I can understand that fragment_container_view is not in the view hierarchy because I load the CommentaryViewFragment like this

```
val commentaryViewFragment = CommentaryViewFragment(commentaryNote)
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.let { commentaryViewFragment.show(it, commentaryViewFragment.tag) }
```

from Fragment1.

So the question is How i can add the CommentaryViewFragment in the FragmentContainerView or is there some other better way to achieve this, so I can move from one Fragment to Another in the BottomSheet as well?

Additionally, if I add the `FragmentContainerView` inside the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` layout file then the layout file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/verse_commentary_view"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/commentary_fragment_container_view"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentary_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/crimsonpro"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Testing"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/commentary_close"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/commentary_view_close"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:fontFamily="@font/crimsonpro"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:id="@+id/commentary_text"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the app does not crash but the second Fragment appears on top of the first one

[image]

Here is the additional layout code for main_activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can someone reading this have a clue what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: If you want your fragment to be inside the bottom sheet, where is the `FragmentContainerView` in the bottom sheet's layout XML? There has to be a container inside the bottom sheet to put the fragment.

Comment: I am using the ``FragmentContainerView``from the activity if i add the ``FragmentContainerView``in the XML then the second fragment added via the ``pushNewFragment`` method just becomes visible on top of the existing Fragment. I will update the question to also include that information as well.

Answer (score 0):

`BottomSheetDialogFeagment` is a type of `DialogFragment`. You can use [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started), you can register the `DialogFragment` in your `nav_graph`.

```
<dialog 
android:id="@+id/your_fragment_id"
android:name="com.example.ui.YourDialogFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/your_dialog_fragment_layout" />
```

Then navigate

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_fragment_id)
```

Hopefully it helps.